# Any way to speed up this UPDATE? C#, SQL, T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, t-sql

SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRandomForeNames ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
AS
BEGIN
RETURN  (
            SELECT TOP 1 [FirstName]
            FROM [tmp_ForeNames] 
            ORDER BY (SELECT new_id from GetNewID)
        )
END
GO
```

Similar functions for dbo.fnRandomSurNames() etc.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET firstname = dbo.fnRandomForeNames(),
    lastname = dbo.fnRandomSurNames(),
    address1 = dbo.fnRandomAddress1(),
    address2 = dbo.fnRandomAddress2(),
    address3 = dbo.fnRandomAddress3(),
    birthdate = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 3650), '1990-01-01')
```

My C# Code:

```
    private void RunThis(string connString, StreamReader sr)
    {
        sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        string sqlQuery = sr.ReadToEnd();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
            server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 4200;
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlQuery);
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
```

........

```
 RunThis(e.Argument.ToString(), _updateClaim);
```

Where `e.Argument.ToString()` is the connection string.

The `CREATE FUNCTION` scripts are run earlier, take very little time to run.
Also, names are stored in tmp databases, these are entered in C# via arrays.
These also take very little time to run.

Table1 contains approx 140,000 rows and takes approx. 14 mins to complete.

I have also tried using parameterised SQL queries, skipping the tmp tables and SQL functions and instead creating the SQL query and executing it from the code, such as the following:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET lastname = '{0}',
    firstname = '{1}',
    birthdate = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 3650), '1990-01-01'),
    address1 = '{2}',
    address2 = '{3}',
    address3 = '{4}'
    WHERE u_id = '{6}'
```

And some C#:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
            {
                string updateString = string.Format(updateString2, GetRandomSurname(), GetRandomForeName(), GetRandomAddress1(), GetRandomAddress2(), GetRandomAddress3(), "", ids[i]);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateString, connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

The latter method also taking upwards of 14 minutes.

Any ideas on how to cut down the time it takes to update the table?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you put your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: are their any index(s) over the columns of the table?

Comment: What is Server that takes ServerConnection, I mean is that a 3rd party code, also you need to wrap it with using statement

Comment: @rshetye No, there are no indexes

Comment: @HatSoft Server is a class in Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.SMO   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The first update is slow, because of the functions. They are simply running too many times.

In the second case the checksum could take too many time.

Just a hint may you can try it:

What do you think about a solution where you put an IDENTITY column on each temp table, simply giving them id-s and then just have to use joins in the sql, and only throwing some Random values in c# like foreign keys to the temp tables. With the rows you can inserts the new id based records first, and then run only one big update on the main table. First is may an overkill but I think it could make a better result. In the past we used something like this for prefill  some testdatabase.

P.S.: I used android phone sorry because of typos and readability:)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to looks at create a single [table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to return a table with those random values in it, instead of making multiple calls to multiple functions.  Something like this:

```
create function dbo.fnRandomStuff
(
  @FirstName bit, 
  @LastName bit, 
  @address1 bit,
  @address2 bit,
  @address3 bit
)
RETURNS @RandomStuff TABLE 
(
    FirstName varchar(50) NULL, 
    LastName varchar(50) NULL, 
    address1 varchar(50) NULL, 
    address2 varchar(50) NULL, 
    address3 varchar(50) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
  -- your code here to get the random stuff based on the 
  -- parameters passed

END
```

Then since you are returning a table, you can join on the table and it will minimize the multiple calls that you are making to your functions.